# AngularJS — Ng-repeat through objects of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I just started playing around with Angular JS a few days ago.  I have this array called `posts` that has objects in it, which I want to be displayed and categorized by the year in which they have been posted.

This is the `posts` array:

```
var posts = [
    {
        title: "First Blog Post of 2015",
        date: "06/24/15",
        content: "This is the first post of the year 2015."
    }, {
        title: "Second Blog Post of 2015",
        date: "07/01/15",
        content: "This is the second post of the year 2015."
    }, {
        title: "First Blog Post of 2014",
        date: "07/11/14",
        content: "This is the first post of the year 2014."
    }
];
```

As you can see, the `posts` array contains 3 objects, which represent posts.  Each "post" has a title, date, and some content.  I want to order them like so:

[image]

This is what I currently have:

[image]

I was able to access the year, but I can't get into the child objects.

This is what you see in the console when you do `console.log($scope.postsByYear);`:
[image]

I wrote a script that puts the posts in the arrays based on the year in which they have been recorded.  It just takes apart the post's date property, which has a date format of `mm/dd/yy`.  I don't know how to `ng-repeat` those objects within the `posts` array.

This is what I have:

```
<div>
    <h1>Blog</h1>
    <ul ng-repeat="year in postsByYear">
        <li>{{year.year}}</li>
        <li ng-repeat="post in postsByYear.posts">{{post.title}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have absolutely no idea why this code isn't working.  It gets the date fine, but it cannot access the properties of the post objects.  It make sense, right?  Post is a placeholder for one of the post objects, and `postsByYear.posts` should select the title in all the objects...

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ptq0paj3/1/) is the jsFiddle link to the code.  Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a simple mistake. In your inner repeat, you're looping over the wrong object. Should be

```
<li ng-repeat="post in year.posts">{{post.title}}</li>
```